# scrolling for div only and div overflow issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to apply scroll event to one of element

```
<div style="position: fixed;width: 30px;height: 300px;overflow: hidden;left: 50%;margin-left: -15px;text-align: center" id="chars_con">
    <?php
    for($i = 97; $i <= 122; $i++){
    ?>
    <div class="chars" ch_to="<?php echo "chars$i"; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper(chr($i));?><div class="chars_a" id="<?php echo "chars$i"; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper(chr($i));?></div></div>
        <?php }
    ?>
</div>
```

**my javascript**

```
window.onload=function(){
        $(".chars").hover(function(){
            $("#"+$(this).attr("ch_to")).show();
        },function(){
            $("#"+$(this).attr("ch_to")).hide();
        });
        $("#chars_con").hover(function(){
            $("#chars_con").css({marginTop:$("#chars_con").scrollTop()});
        },function(){

        });
    }
```

**css**

```
div.chars{background-color: #66ccff;padding: 3px 7px;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer}
    div.chars:hover{background-color: #990099;color: #ffffff}
    div.chars_a{background-color: #0000ff;color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid #ffff00;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;text-align: center;position: absolute;padding: 10px 15px;display: none;margin-left: -13px;margin-top: -25px;overflow: visible}
```

Overflow issue : i am not able explain this so please remove overflow:hidden form div:#chars_con and see the effect .. i want to do extaly like when we don't have overflow:hidden. but i want to keep this property because i want to apply scroll effect to this

Scroll issue: i want to scroll this div when i mouse hover it and do scroll

Please ask any question because i am not able to explain but you can get it from the code i mentioned here

Comment: You can't create your own custom attributes in HTML, and even if you did, you can't show and hide them.

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, replace `window.onload=function(){` with `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Comment: Do you want to move the `<div>` down, or scroll it's contents?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff i want to apply scroll effect but dont want to show scroll bar ...something similar effect like touchscreen device

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wEKhG/) what you are after, or do you want it to scroll as you move your mouse up?

Comment: hmmm exactly like this but want to scroll this when i scroll down or up

Comment: You mean you want it to scroll up when you move your mouse up, and scroll down when you move your mouse down?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff post your code in answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough example of touchscreen-style scrolling:

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var last_pos = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scroll').mousemove(function(e) {
        if(e.clientY > last_pos) {
            $('#scroll').scrollTop($('#scroll').scrollTop() - 5);
        } else {
            $('#scroll').scrollTop($('#scroll').scrollTop() + 5);
        }
        last_pos = e.clientY;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="scroll">
    This text will scroll.<br />
    Line 2<br />
    Line 3<br />
    Blah blah<br />
    This text will scroll.<br />
    This text will scroll.<br />
    This text will scroll.<br />
    Line ?<br />
    Line ?++<br />
    This text will scroll.<br />
    This text will scroll.<br />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#scroll {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wEKhG/1/**

Comment: A little improvement to your mousemove function: change the if to `$('#scroll').scrollTop($('#scroll').scrollTop() - e.clientY + last_pos);` http://jsfiddle.net/wEKhG/2/

Comment: @darksky - Your code resets the scrolling position if you mouse out then mouse in again. You cannot reach the end of the text.

Comment: **@all: `- 5`/`+ 5` can be changed to `- 1`/`+ 1` for much smoother scrolling.**

Answer (score -2):

From my understanding of your problem, I think you want to have a div with scroll hidden and only want to show the scroll bar when hovered over it. If that is the case, you can do it in a simple way as follows

```
<div id="division_to_scroll" style='{overflow:hidden}'/>
```

and then attach a jquery event on mouseover

```
$('#division_to_scroll').mouseenter(function(){
$('#division_to_scroll').css("overflow", "scroll");}).mouseleave(function(){$('#division_to_scroll').css("overflow", "hidden");});​
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLw4u/)